# Is the Yoneda bijection natural in the domain category?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, yoneda-lemma

In the Yoneda Lemma, we start with a locally small category (the domain category, sometimes called a *site*), together with some other data, and establish a certain bijection.
What is the naturality (or functorality) of the bijection under change of domain categories, first via a functor, then under a natural transformation between such functors?  (Without going into the gory details here, are there some textbooks or papers that answer that question?)

Comment: The isomorphism $Nat(y_A,F) \cong FA$ is natural "in all possible arguments": in $A$, as an isomorphism of functors $\lambda T. Nat(y_T,F)\cong F$, and in $F$, if you write"ev" for the evaluation functor $(A,F)\mapsto FA$, as an isomorphism of functors $Nat(y_A,-)\cong \text{ev}(A,-)$.

Comment: If what you're asking is a naturality "in the category on which a presheaf F is defined", there's another sense in which you can answer positively, but it requires more gory details and a bit of 2-dimensional CT.

Comment: To fosco: In your first comment, $A$ is an object in the domain category, $F$ is a functor from that category into the base category $\mathbf{\text{Set}}$. The naturality of the Yoneda bijection in those arguments, $A$ and $F$, is a lemma in the discussion of the bijection in Mac Lane's CWM. On your second comment, yes, I used "domain category" as shorthand for your "category on which a presheaf F is defined". Finally, on your last point, can you provide references?

Answer (score 2):

$\require{AMScd}$I suspect this is not what you were asking, but it's the only way in which it makes sense to answer.

Let's say you have a functor $H : \mathcal C \to \mathcal D$. You can use it in the diagram
$$\begin{CD}
\mathcal C @>y>> [\mathcal{C}^\text{op},{\bf Set}] \\ 
@VHVV@. \\
\mathcal D @>>y> [\mathcal{D}^\text{op},{\bf Set}] \\
\end{CD}$$
and now you have two choices to fill this with a functor between the presheaf categories, because $H$ induces a pair of adjoint functors
$$
H^* : [\mathcal D^\text{op},{\bf Set}] \rightleftarrows [\mathcal C^\text{op}, {\bf Set}] : H_*
$$
$H^*$ precomposes $H$ (well, to be precise, the opposite functor $H^\text{op}$) to a functor $F : \mathcal D \to \bf Set$ in order to obtain a functor $FH : \mathcal C^\text{op} \to \bf Set$. $H_*$ acts in a more complicated way, it is a [certain colimit](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Yoneda+extension) built out of $H$ and a presheaf $G$ on $\mathcal C$.

Now, choosing $H^*$ to fill the diagram you don't get a naturality square, and not even a commutative diagram, because there is just a natural transformation filling it, which is invertible if and only if $H$ is fully faithful (try to prove it).

Choosing $H_*$ turns out to give you a (pseudo)commutative square, which is already better. But the definition of $H_*$ is quite elusive!

Comment: Do you mean $H_!$ (the left adjoint) here?

Comment: Oh no, I switched their direction. Yes, $H^*$ has a *left* adjoint...